# 97 Mazda protege coolant boiling over

Tags: engine, coolant

Why does my coolant reservoir boil over after I shut off the engine? Temp gauge doesn't move while I'm driving. I just replaced the radiator cap. It's better now, but still boils over. I see one fan that comes on, but the other does not.

Comment: Is this a new problem?  Did it start AFTER you replaced the cap or before?

Comment: No it was actually worse before. I see one fan turn on, but the second fan doesn't.

Comment: Details like those should be included in the OP. Please edit it.